# Swfloader scale content to full size

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, swfloader

I have load flash swf file to my flex project. 
I have used `SWFLoader` for that to load the swf file.

```
var loader:SWFLoader = new SWFLoader();
loader.load("player/VideoPlayer.swf");
loader.width = 320;
loader.height = 280;
parentContainer.addElement(loader);
```

In which `parentContainer` is `<s:BorderContainer`. It's width 320 and height 280.

I have also tried to set like following, but didn't got succeeded:

```
function onComplete(event:Event):void
{
    loader.width = 320;
    loader.height = 280;
}
```

**Problem:** But when i run it swf file load to full width and height. 
 How can i set it's width and height to it's parent container?

I have also tried like:

```
<s:BorderContainer id="parentContainer" width="320" height="280">

    <s:SWFLoader width="320" height="280" scaleContent="false" autoLoad="true"
                         source="@Embed(source='player/VideoPlayer.swf')"  />
</s:BorderContainer>
```

But still it take 100% size of application. Application size is 600 X 500.

**Edit:**

**`swfloader`** cover whole application and all other flex component hide beside the **`swfloader`**

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> **scaleContent**
>   A flag that indicates whether to scale the content to fit the size of the control or resize the control to the content's size. If true, the content scales to fit the SWFLoader control. If false, the SWFLoader scales to fit the content.

I do not know why do not work because the default value for `scaleContent` is `true`, try to set the property:

```
<s:BorderContainer id="parentContainer" width="320" height="280">

    <s:SWFLoader width="320" height="280" scaleContent="true" autoLoad="true"
                     source="@Embed(source='player/VideoPlayer.swf')"  />
</s:BorderContainer>
```

Or:

```
var loader:SWFLoader = new SWFLoader();
loader.load("player/VideoPlayer.swf");
loader.width = 320;
loader.height = 280;
loader.scaleContent = true;
parentContainer.addElement(loader);
```

Comment: swfloader cover whole application and all other flex component hide beside the swfloader

Comment: Have you tried to load another `swf` with same dimensions?
Maybe the problem is not in your code but in the loaded `swf`.